# CH340: right endpoint?

Tags: arduino-uno, usb, uart

I'm working on implementing CH340 drivers used by cheap Arduino clones on Android (Linux). What endpoints should be used as read endpoint since two endpoints have IN flag - 0x81 and 0x82?

http://usbdriverwriting.blogspot.ru/2012/10/connection-status-device-connected.html

Is there any developer documentation except some old c #1 (http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/drivers/usb/serial/ch341.c?v=2.6.25.8) and some linux driver #2 (http://0xcf.com/?wpdmdl=124)

Comment: Try looking at the (normal) Linux drivers source code.  Of course, you could always try one and see - if it doesn't work, try the other instead.

Comment: can you send me the link for normal Linux driver sources for CH340 chip?

Comment: none if them is working because of another reasons so i can't detect which one is correct. i need just to know which one is right

Comment: Plug it into a linux machine and use `lsusb -v -d <vid:pid>` to find which endpoint is the bulk one?  You can probably do something similar on Windows but I don't have a clue how.

Comment: according to the link above (http://usbdriverwriting.blogspot.ru/2012/10/connection-status-device-connected.html) 0x82 is bulk endpoint and 0x81 is not

Comment: So it should be 0x82 then I would guess.  The other one is probably for sending configuration or control line messages.

Comment: thanks for help, Majenko. If someone has any documentation on this please share it

Comment: The trouble with cheap Chinese chips is that you get cheap Chinese datasheets. "You gets what you pays for" as they say.